# How to automatically pause a video in html?

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, html5-video

I am making a Starbuzz coffee Webpage, in which I am putting some videos. Whenever I come on that page, the video starts automatically. Even without me clicking on the play button. I want the video to only start when the user clicks on the play button.

I use the `<video>` command.

Basically I want the video to be put in pause by default. I use Google Chrome. Is there a way to do that?

My code is:

```
<article>
<video controls width="512" height="288" autoplay>
    <source src="Starbucks Coffee Perfection.mp4">
    <source src="Starbucks Coffee Perfection.webm">
    <p>Sorry, your browser doesn't support the video element.</p>
</video>
</article>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How video is been added to website?

If you use `<embed>` add `autoplay="false"`

else, if you use `<object>` add `<param name="play" value="false" />`

else if it's `<iframe>` add `autoplay=0` to source link of included video

EDIT:
I forgot about `<video>` :D
If you add video using this tag, delete `autoplay` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `autoplay`

```
    <article>
    <video controls width="512" height="288">
        <source src="Starbucks Coffee Perfection.mp4">
        <source src="Starbucks Coffee Perfection.webm">
        <p>Sorry, your browser doesn't support the video element.</p>
    </video>
    </article>
```

Comment: This is answered already in https://stackoverflow.com/a/29745191/4711785

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to upload the video onto youtube and then embed the video from there it does this automatically

Comment: So how do you suggest I upload the video onto youtube and embed the video from there?